# How to download subtree with ftp

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I have to download a whole subtree of directories and files from an ftp server to my own local pc (Ubuntu). Normally a GUI like gFTP or Filezilla would do the trick, but on this ftp server I have to authenticate myself with a site group [user] and site gpass [password] command.

When using the tool `ftp` I can only download the files of one directory (mget) at a time, not a whole subtree.

How can I do this. I would not like to install any software that is not in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is just that you need to authenticate with a username and password?

Comment: @Andy Part of the problem. This server works like this and I cannot change it. Filezilla et al. are seemingly not supporting to always executing this command for every connection, making it possible to browse the ftp (because for that I can give custom commands), but not to download (because it makes a new connection without the commands)

Comment: OK so you want an application that allows you to execute custom commands at the start of every connection?

Comment: @Andy: Yes, indeed. So your answer did the trick :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Filezilla, you can try this, taken from [the Filezilla forums](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12768).

**Q:**

> It should be possible to configure one or more custom commands to be executed after connect (like setting the initial default remote directory).
>
> A sample use case is connecting to an iSeries (AS/400): Depending on the configuration of the FTP server you have to issue the custom command "SITE NAMEFMT 1" before transferring files.

**A:**

> There is an undocumented feature: PostLoginCommands.
>
> Code:

```
<PostLoginCommands>
<Command>command1</Command>
<Command>command2</Command>
<Command>command3</Command>
.
.
.
</PostLoginCommands>
```

> Must be entered directly into the `<server>` block in `sitemanager.xml`.

Not tested, but I think that's the right kind of thing for you?

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `wget` instead. Something like this:

```
wget -m ftp://username:password@host/folder/
```

See [Using wget to recursively download whole FTP directories](https://serverfault.com/questions/25199/using-wget-to-recursively-download-whole-ftp-directories).

Comment: How about the site group and site gpass commmands? It seems wget can not handle this!

Comment: Don't even know what that is :p Sorry!